# How to index simple javascript hash/objects with ctags?

Tags: javascript, exuberant-ctags

I use ctags to navigate my javascript apps and found that functions are added to the index and work great, yet when I have a seemingly basic hash/object it isn't added to the index/ctags file when I index using the command below. Anything I can add to this command or that I should know about ctags to change this behavior?

> ctags -a -Rf .ctags --languages=javascript,typescript
>   --exclude=.git --exclude="*.min.js" --exclude=node_modules

here is the javascript object in question

```
var MyAsyncComponent = {
  hello: null,
  render: function() {
    return "abc123";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because you are not using the correct JavaScript ctags definition file.

I was just trying you example out using a definition by Tim-Smart which he posted over on [Github in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/tim-smart/199338).

All you have to do is include that in your .ctag definition file in your home directory (/~) and then run:

```
ctags --languages=js <name of js file(s)>
```

That way you will produce a tags file that can be consumed by an editor or IDE.

I hope this helps. I just tried it with Sublime Text 2 and the Ctags plugin and I was able to navigate to the objects attribute without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Universa-ctags(https://ctags.io) can capture the hash/object.

```
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% cat > foo.js
var MyAsyncComponent = {
  hello: null,
  render: function() {
    return "abc123";
  }
};
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags -o - foo.js
MyAsyncComponent    foo.js  /^var MyAsyncComponent = {$/;"  c
hello   foo.js  /^  hello: null,$/;"    p   class:MyAsyncComponent
render  foo.js  /^  render: function() {$/;"    m   class:MyAsyncComponent
```